# How to display adjacent sibling on hover using SASS?

Tags: css, sass

```css
.parent{
  &__child-1:hover + &__child-2{
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sass.js/0.6.2/sass.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="parent__child-1">child 1</div>
  <div class="parent__child-2">child 2</div>
  <div class="parent__child-3">child 3</div>
</div>
```

Hello, I'm trying to target an adjacent sibling of an element. The method I used works with CSS but doesn't work with SASS, is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: The sass is sound. Have you tried in an online sandbox environment that compiles the sass to test it out? Perhaps there's something else at negating this css?

Comment: yes, just tried it on codesandbox.io, it works as expected but it doesn't work on my vscode although other SASS styling are working